# "Plotly" cannot import in Jupyter

Tags: plotly

I tried to import "plotly" in jupter but the below error message popped out. Not sure if anyone can help with? Thank you very much!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTrGy.jpg)

I have tried to import the library but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have `plotly` installed in a different environment, not the one that `jupyter` uses. I find this post useful when installing modules in `jupyter` https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/

Particularly, I usually use this approach from inside jupyter:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install plotly
```

Comment: This is referencing outdated information. You can use a more convenient user-friendly command that will work in all sorts of modern Jupyter, such as JupyterLite. (But not Google Colab at present because it is built on outdated tech, sadly.) Current best practice to use the magic install commands would **theoretically** be here: `%pip install plotly` run inside a notebook. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic install commands that insure installation occurs in the correct ...

Comment: <continued> environment where the kernel is running that is underlying the active notebook. I added **theoretically** in this case because Plotly tends to be a more complex installation then a lot of packages. It uses extensions and such to handle hooking the interactive nature of the output it can generate. So it may work with installing from inside a notebook; however, it may not or may require restarting everything after the attempt to propagate all the changes needed. In other words you mileage may vary in this case; however, in general use the modern magic install commands.